# EF6 generating unneeded SQL query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm wondering why the generated SQL is checking for nulls on a column that is not nullable (column `Value`  which is a not-null float),

```
var query = _context.Events
  .Select(e => new
  {
    eventId = e.EventId,
    data = e.Data.Take(10).Select(x => new
    {
      name = x.Name,
      value = Math.Round(x.Value,1),
    })
  });
```

Generates the following SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    [Project2].[EventId] AS [EventId], 
    [Project2].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], 
    [Project2].[TimeEnd] AS [TimeEnd], 
    [Project2].[C2] AS [C1], 
    [Project2].[EventId1] AS [EventId1], 
    [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project2].[C1] AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Limit1].[EventId] AS [EventId], 
        [Limit1].[TimeEnd] AS [TimeEnd], 
        [Limit1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent2].[EventId] AS [EventId1], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Value] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS float) ELSE ROUND([Extent2].[Value], 1) END AS [C1], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Value] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
        FROM   (SELECT [Project1].[EventId] AS [EventId], [Project1].[TimeEnd] AS [TimeEnd], [Project1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[EventId] AS [EventId], 
                [Extent1].[TimeEnd] AS [TimeEnd], 
                [Extent1].[DeviceId] AS [DeviceId]
                FROM [dbo].[Events] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[DeviceId] = 1)
            )  AS [Project1]
            ORDER BY [Project1].[TimeEnd] DESC ) AS [Limit1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Octaves] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[EventId] = [Extent2].[EventId]
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[TimeEnd] DESC, [Project2].[EventId] ASC, [Project2].[C2] ASC
```

If I remove the two `CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Value] IS NULL)` and just leave `ROUND([Limit2].[Value], 1) AS [C1]` and also remove the `ORDER BY Project2].[C2] ASC` in SQL Server Management the query speeds up.

Comment: In your EF model, you should check whether the fields are nullable or not.

Comment: @teocomi  
How long does the query take if you run it as is? If you then remove the CASE? If you then remove the CASE and the order by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a LEFT OUTER JOIN, so the values (in the query) can definitely be NULL (even if the underlying table definition is not nullable).

See http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html (for Oracle - but the same basic pattern applies for all the main SQL vendors).

*In this case, it is a bit pointless since ROUND(NULL, 1) would return NULL anyway (well, it would on SQL Server). But there isn't much you can do about that, given you can't control the SQL it generates.*